# Cosmos db java api result same record in a list

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using cosmos client in java for connecting Cosmos db. I am successful to get the data but when there are multiple records matching the where condition i get the same elements in the list.for example if 10 records match then also same records is coming 10 times  The container has partition key . Any help

Comment: Hello and welcome to the community ;). Plz make sure to share at least some of your code here (what you have tried so far, what the records look like etc..)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please edit to show your query, sample input, and expected vs actual output. Probably helps to show both the raw SQL query as well as your Java code (to see how you're attempting to read the results). Be sure to include all details, such as Cosmos DB SDK version, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Column_Name FROM TestTable1 WHERE Column_Name in ('dup1','dup1','dup2')
```

Using the **DISTINCT** can retrieve only the normal values by avoiding the duplicate from DB.